Header on Homepage vs in blog
I'm using a free theme for Blogger.com. I've uploaded my logo. It sits on top of a hero image on the homepage and looks good.
When I go to the blog section there is a huge gap between the logo and where the blog post title starts.
Without <p></p> in the widget section: https://natrunsfardev.blogspot.com/ | https://natrunsfardev.blogspot.com/2024/04/blog-post.html
With <p></p> in the widget section:
In the layout, if I remove a widget between the header widget and the main blog widget the gap on the blog page is fine but the logo on the home screen drops down to the middle of the hero image. If the put <p></p> back in the widget between the header and main widgets the homepage logo placement is fine but the gap on the blog page is back. It takes up almost everything above the fold.
Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you!
Changing the padding on the header. There is movement on the homepage but still ha large distance between the logo and top left of page.
